# GM_addStyle function is not working in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm using Tampermonkey and trying to change the CSS of the body tag. However the usual way to add CSS doesn't work,

`GM_addStyle("body {overflow:visible !important}");`

I think because the CSS I'm trying to change is added inline by a script. Dev tools indicates `overflow: hidden` is an inline style; and the overflow: hidden style only appears in dev tools, not in "view source".

`<body class="fixed-scroll-nav blah-blah-blah" style="overflow: hidden;">`

I have the Tampermonkey script set to run at `document-end`. I can manually add overflow: hidden in dev tools and confirm it's the correct selector.

Do I need a different JavaScript or Tampermonkey function?

Comment: Something else is going on. (1) Link to the target page (or provide a [mcve]). (2) Is the script using `document-start`? (3) Browser version? Tampermonkey version? (4) Verify that the script does `@grant GM_addStyle`.

Comment: Also, there should be a semicolon after `!important` (but that's probably not the issue for most browsers).

Comment: Ah, my bad.  `// @grant GM_addStyle` was missing. Fixed. Add that as your answer. Thanks!